# configure an android application

Tags: android

Guys, I need an android application that can be configured by the user. In java, we are using properties file to configure the applications. Any idea about the same in android..

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of configuration do you want to do? Care to be more specific?

Comment: I can't see the real problem. Clarify with some code.

Comment: In this application i need to use httpconnection. The url for this is user defined. how can implement this???

Answer (score 1):

I can guess you need preferences.
You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) or [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) ([this article](http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences) will be a good start).

Comment: thank you cement, Is .Editor file accessible and editable for user from outside the application?? if yes where will be the location of the file???

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/25/getting-sharedpreferences-from-other-application-in-android/

Comment: There is a screenshot in the bottom of the article: http://thedevelopersinfo.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/file_system.PNG

Comment: cement, I think this is the location of that files in the system.. In my android device the user gets the executable file only. the user have to configure the application. then how can we get from the device??

Answer (score 0):

If you want your files that can beaccessed from outside you should have some xml file in your resource folder or you can also sed a file along with your application and store iton external memory as andorid do not provide you feature of acessing private datas, toa ccess private datas u need content providers that will be overhead as in your case..
hence better, u bundle a xml file along with you app, which at deployment need to save a copy at sd card and once its there everytime you should check for that file..
this way user will be able to chnge the contents without even running the program, also other application will be able to access youir file

hope this helps